# Windows can't verify libusb-win32's publisher

Tags: driver, signing, libusb

I am trying to install libusb-win32-1.2.6.0, which comes with a valid digital signature.
But when installing I still get a popup from Windows: "Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software".

I also imported the certificate in Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Trusted Publishers.

Is there a method to avoid this warning?

Comment: it's a warning, so you can still continue.  the only way to avoid it is to sign the driver with a valid certificate.  this is like that for security reasons.  there may be a registry key that you can set to disable cert checking, but i am not sure.  they might have taken this out.  what windows version are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, 32 bit. I want to get rid of the warning for automating an installation.